# Updating a previously printed line(in CLI) with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-interface

I am developing a command line game with Python and I want to implement a function that puts a time limit for the player to answer. Basically what I want to do is to update the first line(after printed) to go from:

```
    "5.."
    "5 + 3 = ?"
```

to:

```
   "5..4..3..2..1..Lost"
   "5 + 3 = ?"
```

After 5 seconds

---

```
    print "5..3..2..1..Lost"
    print "5 + 3 = ?"
```

Comment: `/b` is a backspace character, and `/r` is a carriage return in Linux. If you haven't printed a newline, you can simply print `\b * charNumber`, or print a carriage return and make sure your second string is at least as long as the first.

Comment: Take a look at Python's ``curses`` module - it lets you arbitrarily move the cursor around in a text-based application.  I'm not exactly sure how you'd implement these timed messages during user input, but the capability is probably in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print(num, end='\r')`

The `end=` keyword is why this works, `print()` ends in a newline `\n` character, but this can be replaced with any string such as ending the line with a carriage return instead returns the cursor to the start of the current line. You will need to `from __future__ import print_function` with python2.7

As for receiving input at the same time you will need to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module and print the updating counter in a thread

```
import time
from _thread import *
def printcount(secs):
    i=5
    while i != 0:
        print(i, end='\r')
        i -= 1
        time.sleep(secs)

start_new_thread(printcount, (1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a game, you want full control over the console output, not just the current line. You want something like Python's built-in `curses` module.

Take a look at [this little game](https://github.com/yebrahim/ascii-minesweeper) I created using curses, it modifies the console output all over the screen so that might help.